# Find the total work done by the force field F

Tags: vector-analysis

Find the total work done in moving a particle in a force field given by:

$F=(y^2-x^2)i+(2-x+y)j$ along the curve $y=x^3$, from $(-1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$

Help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your definition of "work"?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question! I rewrote the question, is it any clearer now what I am looking for?

Comment: I know what you are looking for.  I am just wondering which definition of "work" to use in my answer.  What is the definition of "work" that you use?  Include it in the statement of your problem.

Comment: I believe 'my' definition of the work of F would be the integral of work elements, dW. Is that it? I must say that I am probably a bit unclear on all the definitions :).

Comment: More elementary I would say that I am looking for the energy that the field adds to the particle ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a constant force and a linear motion, work is given by finding the component of the force acting in the direction of motion and then multiplying that by the distance over which you travel. Things are more difficult when you're moving in the plane.

Let ${\bf x}(t)$ give the path along which you move, then $\dot{\bf x}(t) = {\bf v}(t)$ gives the direction of (instantaneous) motion and so the scaler product $\langle {\bf F},{\bf v}\rangle$, also called the dot product and written ${\bf F} \cdot {\bf v}$, gives the component of the force in the direction of (instantaneous) motion. The instantaneous version of multiplication is integration, and so $W = F\times d$ becomes
$$W=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} {\bf F} \cdot {\bf v} \, \operatorname{d}\!t$$

Your paths has the equation $y=x^3$ with $-1 \le x \le 1$. We can parametrise this as $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=t^3$ where $-1 \le t \le 1$. In vector form: ${\bf x}(t) = t{\bf i} + t^3{\bf j}$. The force can be re-written:
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\bf F}(x,y) &=& (y^2-x^2){\bf i} + (2-x+y){\bf j} \\ \\
{\bf F}(t) &=& (t^6-t^2){\bf i} + (2-t+t^3){\bf j}
\end{eqnarray*}
Finally, ${\bf v}(t) = \dot{\bf x}(t) = {\bf i} + 3t^2{\bf j}$. Hence:
\begin{eqnarray*}
W &=& \int_{t_1}^{t_2} {\bf F} \cdot {\bf v} \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\ \\
&=& \int_{-1}^1 \left((t^6-t^2){\bf i} + (2-t+t^3){\bf j}\right) \cdot \left({\bf i} + 3t^2{\bf j}\right) \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\ \\
&=& \int_{-1}^1 t^6-t^2+6t^2-3t^3+3t^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\ \\
&=& \int_{-1}^1 t^6+5t^2-3t^3+3t^5 \, \operatorname{d}\!t \\ \\
&=& \left[ \tfrac{1}{7}t^7+\tfrac{5}{3}t^3-\tfrac{3}{4}t^4+\tfrac{1}{2}t^6 \right]_{-1}^1 \\ \\
&=& \tfrac{76}{21}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: A nit:  we weren't given units, so don't know that it is joules, ergs, dyne-fathoms or ???

Comment: I think lb. Angstroms?

Comment: @RossMillikan One school of thought is that, unless stated, units are SI and so displacement is in metres and force is in newtons, so work must be in joules. Having said that, if this is the case then I ought not mention joules either in order to be consistent with omission of SI units. Thanks Ross.

Answer (score 2):

The work done by a force $f$ on a particle moving through a suitably smooth curve $\gamma$ on the interval $[t_0,t_1]$ is given by $W = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \langle f(t), \dot{\gamma}(t) \rangle dt$.

Here we can parameterize the curve by $\gamma(t) = (t,t^3)$ for $t \in [-1,1]$.

We have $f(t) = F(\gamma(t)) = (t^6-t^2,t^3-t+2)$, and $\dot{\gamma}(t) = (1,3t^2)$.

Hence $ W = \int_{-1}^1 (t^6-t^2+3 t^2(t^3-t+2)) dt = \frac{76}{21}$.